# Why use process.nextTick to ensure correct execution of asynchronous tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am following an example of a book ([Node.js design patterns](https://www.amazon.es/Node-js-Design-Patterns-production-grade-applications/dp/1839214112/ref=pd_lpo_14_t_0/259-1666535-2336308?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1839214112&pd_rd_r=61eb9590-ca46-4930-9157-472611f38861&pd_rd_w=MxE2O&pd_rd_wg=0vRj4&pf_rd_p=4221015a-01c7-4a3d-a84d-985d938e9995&pf_rd_r=KS4D7AN6ATNDFGVMBSPM&psc=1&refRID=KS4D7AN6ATNDFGVMBSPM)) to implement a **LIMITED PARALLEL EXECUTION** algorithm in Node.js with Javascript.

First, I write a TaskQueue class that handles all the limiting and execution of the tasks.

```
class TaskQueue {
    constructor(concurrency) {
        this.concurrency = concurrency;
        this.running = 0;
        this.queue = [];
    }
    runTask(task) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.queue.push(() => {
                return task().then(resolve, reject);
            });
            process.nextTick(this.next.bind(this));
        });
    }
    next() {
        while (this.running < this.concurrency && this.queue.length) {
            const task = this.queue.shift();
            task().finally(() => {
                this.running--;
                this.next();
            });
            this.running++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have written a function that returns a promise that resolves after a random number of miliseconds and keeps record of the promise with an assigned number.

This function delegates the task to the queue, wrapping the promise in a function that will be executed on demand by the TaskQueue class.

```
function promiseResolveRandomValue(promiseNumber, queue) {
    return queue.runTask(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const random = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('Resolved promise number: ', promiseNumber, ' with delay of: ', random);
                resolve();
            }, random);
        });
    })
}
```

Finally I have used a map to execute the function over an array of ten numbers that will help us keep track of each promise.

```
const queue = new TaskQueue(2);
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const promises = array.map((number) => {
    return promiseResolveRandomValue(number, queue);
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => console.log('Finished'));
```

So far so good. The thing is that the author recommends this line of code to be executed with process.nextTick to avoid any Zalgo type of situation, but I don't see why, as this code executes exactly the same just invoking the next method of the class.

```
runTask(task) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.queue.push(() => {
                return task().then(resolve, reject);
            });
            process.nextTick(this.next.bind(this)); // <-------------------------------- WHY?
        });
    }
```

Could someone clarify why is it convenient to use the process.nextTick in some cases such as this one to avoid conflicts with synchronous and asynchronous code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Zalgo situation](https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) the author is referring to would be

```
console.log("Before scheduling the task")
queue.runTask(() => {
    console.log("The task actually starts");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // doesn't really matter:
        setTimeout(resolve, Math.random()*1000);
    });
});
console.log("Scheduled the task");
```

If you didn't use `nextTick`, the logs could happen in a different order - the task might actually start before the `runTask()` function returns, depending on how many there are already in the queue.

This might not be that unexpected - after all, we expect `runTask` to run the task - however if the task actually starts with some side effect synchronously, that might be unexpected. An example for such a side effect would be the `next` method itself - consider the following:

```
queue.runTask(() => …);
console.log(`Scheduled the task, there are now ${queue.queue.length} tasks in the queue`);
```

Would you expect the length to always be at least one? Avoiding Zalgo can give such guarantees.

(On the other hand, if we did log `queue.running` instead, expecting it to be >=1 immediately after calling `runTask` seems just as sensible to me, and would require starting `next` synchronously. Clear documentation trumps any intuition here.)

Comment: This explanation is exactly what I was looking for. I frankly didn't know where the unexpected behaviour of the code was coming from, and It's basically because the Zalgo situation happens in between the runTask method. That helped a lot. Thank you very much!!